# Not desired output from python program

Tags: python-3.x

In the following program I am getting input from user and checking weather it types an int type or string type: if the inserted type is a int then the program terminates with the message "not allowed" while if it is a string type, it return its length.
Here's my program:

```
#Taking i/p from user and counting length if it is string type.
def string_len (word):
    if type(word)==int():
        return "not allowed"
    else:
        return len(word)

word = input("enter a word:")#taking input from user
print(string_len(word))
```

Output:

```
PS E:\> python .\len.py
enter a word:testing
7
PS E:\> python .\len.py
enter a word:9567843   ***# here it should not count length int type so.***
7
```

Here it returns length for int type also, but it should not. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` always returns a string, even if the content is a number.

You should try converting the input string to an integer first, and, if it succeeds, displays the error message you want.

```
def string_len (word):
    try:
        int(word)
        return "not allowed"
    except ValueError:
        return len(word)

word = input("enter a word:")
print(string_len(word))
```